# How & when browsers empty their cache?

Tags: caching, browser-cache

When does chrome empty it's cache?

Is it:

1. When the cache is full, it starts deleting the oldest items?
2. When the Cache-Control max-age expires?
3. When the user shuts down their PC/device?

Is it a mixture of the above?  Are their other scenarios when it empties it's cache?

Also when does the max-age start counting from?  The time the file was first cached, or last used?

Comment: Basically, browser caclulates age starting from either request time or last revalidation request time. For more information check RFC 7234, [Age](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.1) and [Calculating Age](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.3) sections in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on browser implementation.

Causes that I'm aware of:

- Cache has grown to it's maximum size and browser deletes some of cache entries or pieces of sparse cache entries using it's eviction algorithm implementation. For more information check [Cache replacement policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies) page on Wikipedia, [Chromium Disk Cache Eviction](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache#TOC-Eviction) notes, [Mozilla Cache](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Cache_Notes)  notes, [Browser storage limits and eviction criteria](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria)  MDN page.
- User manually clears cache using browser UI. Check [refreshyourcache.com](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/) web site.
- Browser or operating system crashes for some reason and cache state becomes corrupted. Some browsers may delete all cache entries on the next session, others may force cache entries to become stale. Check [Date integrity section](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache) on Chromium HTTP Cache page and [Chromium Very Simple Backend summary](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache/very-simple-backend).
- Browser performs request with unsafe method (PUT, POST, DELETE) and invalidates cache entry with same URI. This behavior described by [RFC 7234 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).
- Web site developers manually manage and clear cache entries using Cache API. Check [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) MDN page.